# Error with SplitView

Tags: ios, ios-universal-app, uisplitview

I have an iphone app that I'm trying to make a universal app.  I created a separate project to play around with creating a split view app for iPad.  I got the basics of it working so I'm trying to implement it in my existing project but I'm getting an error when running on iPad.

```
2013-06-06 08:57:08.716 KFBNewsroom[26898:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "KFBMasterViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

The code for the split view is the same as it was in my test project so I can't figure out why it won't work here. Any ideas?

Here is the code from my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method where I say what to load on different devices.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
        self.viewController = [[KFBViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KFBViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
}
else
{   
        masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

        self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
        self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
}
```

MasterViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class KFBDetailViewController;

@interface KFBMasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) KFBDetailViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

MasterViewController.m:

```
#import "KFBMasterViewController.h"
#import "KFBDetailViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewManager.h"

@interface KFBMasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
    NSMutableArray *menu;
}
@end

@implementation KFBMasterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    menu = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Home", @"Public Affairs", @"Action Alerts", @"Market Updates", @"Ag Stories", @"KFB News", @"Member Benefits", @"Monthly Video", @"Photos", @"Social Media", @"About Us", @"Contact Us", @"KYFB.com", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return menu.count;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CellImage.png"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    // NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    // cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    cell.textLabel.text = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:20.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundView = image;

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

@end
```

Comment: I created mine with a nib and the tableview delegate and datasource are set.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to change the super-class of your rootViewController from UITableViewController to UIViewController.

Comment: I've added my code for my MasterViewController to my original post.  I tried making that a UIViewController instead and adding the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource but I got the same error.